# Android - GCM for development, do I need a physical device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

If I want to use GCM in a development environment, can I use the Android mobile device emulator or do I need a physical device?

I want to run the [GCM Demo Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use an emulator. But it has to be version 2.2 above and contains Google API. Once you created this emulator AVD, goto Settings->Accounts & Sync, then add a google account. Once this is done, you should be ready to register for GCM and receive messages from it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe everything you read in the documentation. Some of it is completely wrong.

For instance, I have a freshly created 2.2 emulator which won't register to GCM; it returns PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR every time. Later emulators work fine.